# Glassfish returns 404 error when try to get file with UTF-8 name

Tags: java, maven, utf-8, glassfish

Here is structure of my minified dummy project:

```
./utf8-test
├── index.html
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── ru.mcmerphy
│           └── utf8-test
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
├── resources
│   ├── foo.txt
│   └── йцукен.txt
└── WEB-INF
    └── glassfish-web.xml
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schem$
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.mcmerphy</groupId>
    <artifactId>utf8-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>utf8-test</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>utf8-test</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http:$
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <locale-charset-map locale="" charset=""/>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Glassfish server configuration(configured via admin page):

```
Network Listeners - URI Encoding: UTF-8
JVM Settings - JVM Options: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

So, problem is:

```
<http://localhost:8080/utf8-test/resources/foo.txt> - Works OK
<http://localhost:8080/utf8-test/resources/йцукен.txt> - 404 Error
```

Besides that, when i deploy via admin page all utf-8 characters converted to ?
But "jar xf" works correctly.
So, my deployment steps are:

1. Deploy application via admin page.
2. Copy war-archive via scp.
3. Unpack archive via jar xf command.
4. Copy resources from manually unpacked war-archive.
5. Delete resources with ? characters.

System information:

- Debian version: 7.8
- Glassfish version: 4.1 (build 13)
- Java version: "1.8.0_31"

BTW there is no problems at windows 8.1 environment.

UPDATE: i use init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/glassfish
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          glassfish
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start glassfish at boot time
# Description:       Enable glassfish.
### END INIT INFO

JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_40
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH

case "$1" in
  start)
        sh /opt/java/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-database
                sh /opt/java/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
    ;;
  stop)
        sh /opt/java/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain
                sh /opt/java/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-database
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/glassfish {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

If i execute `sh glassfish stop` and then `sh glassfish start` - my problem disappears. What is the reason for this?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a file named `фу.txt` in `resources`, which is the natural cause of a 404 error.

Comment: @Saposhiente - sorry, i edited my question: <http://localhost:8080/utf8-test/resources/йцукен.txt> - 404 Error

Answer (score 1):

Just added line `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` in init script, and glassfish start to working correctly.